# My clickatell API is not working properly, do I need to do HTTP GET or POST

Tags: sms, sms-gateway, clickatell

I Purchased an API from clickatell and it  doesn't seem to work even after its checked from the support team. 
What should I select HTTP POST for GET

All the settings are fine, but it doesn't send SMS to buyer

Answer (score 0):

According to the Clickatell API Documentation [here](https://www.clickatell.com/developers/api-documentation/rest-api-send-message/) the SMS sending endpoint expects a POST.